# Unit Conversion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, unit-conversion

I need to convert this expression $ 81752 \left( \frac{BTU}{in^2 h ºR} \right )$ to
$ \left( \frac{Kg}{s^3 ºC} \right )$

Is my draft correct?

$
81752 \left( \frac{BTU}{in^2 h ºR} \right ) \rightarrow \frac{1 BTU}{in^2 h}  = \frac{454,3 W}{m^2} = \frac{1 ºR}{0,5555 K} = \frac{66,846533 W}{m^2 k} = \frac{66,896533 kg}{s^3 K}  
  $
  $
  = \frac{1 K}{-272,2 ºC} = \frac{-2456 Kg}{s^3ºC}
  $

Answer (score 0):

No, it is incorrect.  The fact that you get a negative value should tell you there is a big problem!

Per Kelvin and per degree Celsius are exactly the same.  There is no need for your last conversion step.

Also, you are inappropriately using the equal sign (=) in a several places, but that is a formality I suppose.

I haven't checked the other aspects of the draft.